# Creating iterated SQL `INSERT` statements using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, ajax

I am trying to call an insert statement multiple times within a javascript loop (`requestAnimFrame`) using ajax, but only a single entry will be entered into the table.

Ajax call (`mainpage.php`):

```
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxPHP.php",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                       // alert(err.toString());
                        if (err.status == 200) {
                        }
                        else { alert('Error:' + err.responseText + '  Status: ' + err.status); }
                    }
                });
```

My insert statement (`inserts.php`):

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
$sql = "INSERT INTO testing values( '$x1', '$x2', '$x3','$x4', '$x5', '$x6', '$x7', '$x8', '$x9', '$x10', '$x11')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
```

*Note: the ajax block runs when it is supposed to (it is been reached), but the insert statement does NOT insert a new row, instead it overwrites the first rows values.*

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You're not sending any data by the looks of it so you probably insert a row with ID `0` and overwrite that again and again with nothing.

Comment: The code part that gets the values for your variables from your ajax request is missing. You are vulnerable to sql injection. It would be a great idea to use parameterized prepared statements instead and bind your input values to those parameters.

Comment: @jeroen After a couple hours of trying to figure out what was wrong, it turned out I was had the wrong `Primary key` selected, so the results where just as you stated. Thanks, really shaved off some time looking for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

The error in my program was not the code itself, but the Database structure. The incorrect `Primary Key` was selected which resulted in the new insert statements overwriting the previous rows.